# Independence in Linear Regression

Tags: regression

This is probably a relatively simple question, but are b0 and b1 independent in a simple linear regression model?

Comment: No, they are not independent, as they come from the same set of sample data.  This is the basis of the reason for adjustments such as the Bonferroni Joint Confidence Intervals (this you'll probably learn down the road).  But as a simple comment, no they are not independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "No".

The little bit longer answer is: "Almost Never".  About the only time that they will be independent is when the x variable has been centered to have mean 0.  Other than that case the estimates will be correlated.  If the mean of the x's is greater than 0 then they will be negatively correlated, if it is less than 0 then they will be positively correlated.  Software programs will calculate the correlation and textbooks on regression will show you the formula for the correlation.